# Is it possible to create temporal table in Azure synapse datawarehouse

Tags: azure, parse-error, temporal-tables, azure-synapse-analytics

I m trying to create temporal table in azure synapse datawarehouse.

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Department
(
    DeptID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  , DeptName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  , ManagerID INT NULL
  , ParentDeptID INT NULL
  , ValidFrom DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL
  , ValidTo DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL
)
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.DepartmentHistory));
```

i m getting parse error
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As of August 2023, the Microsoft Learn (documentation) page [Transact-SQL features supported in Azure Synapse SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/overview-features) does not explicitly mention temporal tables or the `FOR SYSTEM_TIME` clause, but the section on `SELECT` statements does mention that

> SELECT statement is supported, but some Transact-SQL query clauses [...] are not supported.

The documentation page for [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16) themselves lists which versions of SQL Server it applies to, and does not include Synapse DW in that list:
[image: screenshot from Microsoft Learn, "Temporal Tables" page: Applies to SQL Server 2016 and later, Azure SQL Database, and Azure SQL Managed Instance]

Combined with the fact that you got a syntax error when you tried, it seems certain that this language feature is not currently supported in Azure Synapse DW. This may, of course, change in the future.